# Mappit! Excel Add-Installed but Not showing

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, add-in, audit

I have downloaded and installed the Mappit! Add-In for Excel.  All went well.  I used it on a file I had and the add-in functioned.

After installation, the add-in showed on the menu bar.  Now, I cannot find the file on the menu bar or anywhere on the ribbon.

I have removed the file, re-extracted it, saved it in the default directory for add-ins for Excel 2013 as well as another location - it's only in one place at a time - and ensured that all locations are showing as a trusted location.

How do I get this to show so I can use it again?  I am not having this issue with other add-ins.

I run Excel 2013 on Windows 8.1.

Comment: Hi (Mappit! author here), are you using V1.11a? I have the configuration you mention above at home so will try it at home tonight.

Comment: Yes, that is the version I have.  In fact, I installed it without any problems and ran it a couple of times, once on a very complicated worksheet.  Really liked what it did.

Comment: What's odd is that I just can't see it on the menu or ribbon, even though it's installed.  Any help is appreciated.  It's a great add-in.

Comment: is the addins menu showing on your ribbon?

Comment: The add-ins tab box is checked in the Customize the Ribbon window in the Options area.

Comment: Mappit!addin is checked in the Add-Ins dialog box.

Comment: Sorry for the multiple messages.  I forget to press alt enter.  I have placed the extracted add-in file in both the default directory for add-ins and another location - not at the same time - both are trusted locations.  Still no show.  I do see another add-in I have from ablebits, which shows as a menu item.

Comment: Can you pls message me at ozbrettdj at yahoo dot com. I will send you an unprotected version of the addin to see if this works